# Webservice is working fine and when i try to bind to xamarin forms project it will keeps on loading in emulator which never ends

Tags: web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, json.net

I am trying bind Webservice values to Xamarin.Forms project. The webservice is working fine, when I run the application I am not getting result in emulator it keeps on loading. Please anyone answer this issue I have been stuck in this from two days.

I have attached image

[image]

And code is here:

```
public async void GetJSON()
        {
            //Check network status   
            if (NetworkCheck.IsInternet())
            {

                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");
                string contactsJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ContactList ObjContactList = new ContactList();
                if (contactsJson != "")
                {
                    //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list  
                    ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(contactsJson);
                }
                //Binding listview with server response    
                listviewConacts.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.contacts;
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("JSONParsing", "No network is available.", "Ok");
            }
            //Hide loader after server response    
            ProgressLoader.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

and my xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="jsonformat.JsonParsingPage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Text="JSON Parsing" FontSize="25" />
            <ListView x:Name="listviewConacts" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding email}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding phone.mobile}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                                <BoxView HeightRequest="2" Margin="0,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the loader? Do you see the list getting results? If you step through it with the debugger, can you see on which line it hangs?

Comment: when i debug it will not go next line after this line var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");

Comment: whether i have not written url in correct format in code ?

Comment: Try to call it with GetStringAsync to get the contents directly

Comment: What happens if you remove the loader? and check without debugger

Comment: it will show blank page if i remove loader

Comment: please put debugger here and check you reach that code
listviewConacts.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.contacts;

Comment: when i debug it is not going to next line after this line

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");

Comment: Is your emulator connected to the network? Can you see its IP address assigned to you network? Have you tried on real device? BTW, you should at some point to wrap the calls with try-catch

Comment: Can you provide ContactList code? I tested this just now and I am getting the json but to test deserialization I need ContactList code, I don't want to recreate it myself

Comment: Could you please post the codes to show where the `GetJson` is called. And also post the codes of `ContactList` please.

Comment: hi guys it is working fine now it was the issue in network, my emulator was not connected to network then i changed the ip address now it is working fine

Comment: public class Phone
    {
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string home { get; set; }
        public string office { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public Phone phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactList
    {
        public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }